# wronskian of solutions of $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y = 0$ is zero. What can I say about $p$ and $q$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

My book is asking about what can I say about $p(t)$ and $g(t)$ when the wronskian of any two solutions of $y''+p(t)y'+q(t)y = 0$ is $0$.

I know a theorem that says that the wronskian of $y_1$ and $y_2$, being solutions for this equations, is:

$$W(y_1,y_2) = c\exp\left(-\int p(t) \ dt\right)$$

but how can equating it to $0$ help me find that $p(t)=0$ as my book says?

Comment: If $W(y_1,y_2)=0$, it means that the two solutions are not independent.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam but how does that proves $p(t) = 0$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think the wording of your problem is precise. First of all, suppose $W(t) = c \neq 0$. Let $y_1, y_2$ be solution of the ode. Then since it can be shown by taking derivative of $W(t) = y_1 y'_2 - y_2 y'_1$ that $W'(t) + p(t) W = 0$, this implies $p(t) = 0$. Note that this argument does not work if $W(t) = 0$.

On the other hand, suppose the book asks "**show** $W(t) = 0$, **given** $p(t) = 0$." Then this is different, since the solutions to $y'' + q(t) y = 0$ are linearly dependent, meaning $W(t) = 0$.